# Releasing to AWS throws exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, clojure, leiningen

We're having a problem releasing to AWS. Running `lein release`, I get this:

```
$ lein release
[ 1 / 8 ] Running lein vcs assert-committed
[ 2 / 8 ] Running lein cljfmt fix
[ 3 / 8 ] Running lein change version leiningen.release/bump-version release
[ 4 / 8 ] Running lein vcs commit
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
java.lang.Exception: Couldn't commit. git exit code: 1
 at leiningen.core.eval$sh_with_exit_code.invokeStatic (eval.clj:212)
    leiningen.core.eval$sh_with_exit_code.doInvoke (eval.clj:200)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:516)
    leiningen.vcs$fn__11904.invokeStatic (vcs.clj:84)
    leiningen.vcs/fn (vcs.clj:78)
    clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke (MultiFn.java:234)
    leiningen.vcs$fn__11904.invokeStatic (vcs.clj:80)
    leiningen.vcs/fn (vcs.clj:78)
    clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke (MultiFn.java:229)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:154)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo (AFn.java:144)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:705)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:669)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:662)
    leiningen.vcs$vcs.invokeStatic (vcs.clj:116)
    leiningen.vcs$vcs.doInvoke (vcs.clj:110)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:425)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:156)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:132)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:705)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:669)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:662)
    leiningen.core.main$partial_task$fn__7376.doInvoke (main.clj:284)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:139)
    clojure.lang.AFunction$1.doInvoke (AFunction.java:31)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:137)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:669)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:662)
    leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invokeStatic (main.clj:334)
    leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invoke (main.clj:320)
    leiningen.core.main$resolve_and_apply.invokeStatic (main.clj:343)
    leiningen.core.main$resolve_and_apply.invoke (main.clj:336)
    leiningen.release$release.invokeStatic (release.clj:137)
    leiningen.release$release.invoke (release.clj:97)
    leiningen.release$release.invokeStatic (release.clj:129)
    leiningen.release$release.invoke (release.clj:97)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:154)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo (AFn.java:144)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:705)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:669)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:662)
    leiningen.core.main$partial_task$fn__7376.doInvoke (main.clj:284)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:410)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:154)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:132)
    clojure.lang.AFunction$1.doInvoke (AFunction.java:31)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:137)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:669)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:662)
    leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invokeStatic (main.clj:334)
    leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invoke (main.clj:320)
    leiningen.core.main$resolve_and_apply.invokeStatic (main.clj:343)
    leiningen.core.main$resolve_and_apply.invoke (main.clj:336)
    leiningen.core.main$_main$fn__7465.invoke (main.clj:453)
    leiningen.core.main$_main.invokeStatic (main.clj:442)
    leiningen.core.main$_main.doInvoke (main.clj:439)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:137)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:705)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:667)
    clojure.main$main_opt.invokeStatic (main.clj:514)
    clojure.main$main_opt.invoke (main.clj:510)
    clojure.main$main.invokeStatic (main.clj:664)
    clojure.main$main.doInvoke (main.clj:616)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:137)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:705)
    clojure.main.main (main.java:40)
```

We had some problems with releasing a faulty commit, and had to do a rollback. And now I don't know where to even start searching for any error.

Comment: Well, whatever it was it resolved itself.

Comment: The error would indicate, that textual change leiningen does in the step 3/8 did not actually change the project.clj.

Comment: Yes, but if I had changes I wasn't allowed to release.